# Visible is not a valid member of PlayerGui "Players.MsveNezers.PlayerGui"

Tags: lua, roblox

I've tried everything, nothing works for me, I need to open the store menu when touching Part. And so that this menu does not open for all players

```
local open = game.Workspace.openPart
local close = game.Workspace.closePart
local frame = script.Parent
frame.Visible = false
local function Shop (otherPart)
    local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(otherPart.Parent.Name)
    if player then
    player.PlayersGui.Shop.Frame.Visible = true
    end
end
open.Touched:Connect(Shop)
```

I looked at different sources for a solution to my problem, tried to change my code, but nothing happened

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNYWh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KkpR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBW2J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, "frame" is equal to "script.Parent".
The parent of the script is "PlayerGUI" which doesn't have a "visible" property.
You may want to put the script under the Frame (named "Frame") to fix the error you screenshotted.

Second thing, you're gonna wanna use a serverscript to detect collision with the part, and then use RemoteEvents to tell it to open the GUI on the specific player who touched the part.

Hope this helps, and good luck!